# Speeding up compilation in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

I'm working on UWP after working for a long time in WPF and compilation is abysmally slow.

I understand why release compilation is slow (net native compilation) but that's disabled in debug yet it still takes a lot of time between F5 and the application being displayed on screen, even for a blank application.

Is there any way to speed this up (even at the cost of runtime performance)? It's really hard to work with when you're used to C# giving you extremely fast compile times and testing after every small changes.

For exemple just a right click and rebuild on a very simple (4 pages, each < 200 line of xaml, and pretty much 0 C#) uwp project takes almost exactly 20 seconds in debug (without .net native) with no project references. Meanwhile a much larger WPF application (dozens of windows, thouthand of lines of codes) takes a few seconds and most of that time is copying child projects!

As suggested you can find a minimal example for download here : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h89qsz66erba3x/WPFUWPCompileSpeed.zip?dl=0

It's just a solution with a blank wpf & blank uwp app. Compilation time for WPF is just over 1 second, for UWP 12 seconds, in each case solution was cleaned and the single project i was testing was right clicked and rebuilt. This is in debug (without .net Native compilation)

Comment: Does your virus checker scan the VS install folders? I found that this caused significant slowdown during compilation. I told the AV to exclude those folders and the compilation speed improved significantly.

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel I don't use any additional security software aside from windows defender, however to be sure i disabled it and there were no significant differences (still ~= 1 sec WPF , ~= 12sec UWP, both blank applications in the same solution)

Comment: Oh, sounds like a UWP thing then. Sorry, can't help further as I don't use UWP. Don't forget that if you find an answer elsewhere to make sure to post it here so others can benefit.

Comment: @IllidanS4 That's not relevant to my question at all

Comment: Are you talking about compilation time or the time when you can see the app on the screen? What is your deployment target (Local machine or simulator)? Maybe compilation is fast, but deployment slow (UWP apps are installed, not simply executed like WPFs).

Comment: @Romasz Comilation time, local machine, in any case not launch time (just right click and rebuild is that slow, even without launching it after)

Comment: @RonanThibaudau I've tried your samples - indeed the WPF compiles within second, whereas UWP needs 2-3 seconds on my side, so in my case it doesn't make big difference. On the other hand - are you aware that you can make small changes within code without rebuilding the project, and see the results while running the app?

Comment: @Romasz To the xaml at runtime yes, but not code changes, i'm just used to the instant compile times in C# and wondering what causes this difference on a blank project. I really want to know why it is that slow (it's slower than a mid sized wpf project for a blank uwp one) and if there's any way to mitigate that compile time, i'm really not working for any other workarounds that require adapting my workflow, it just seems odd that it would take that long as i don't see it "do" anything special, just like in wpf it has to process xaml, compile C#, and i doubt creating a package is that slow

Comment: @RonanThibaudau I meant changes to the code, not xaml. Once you set a brakpoint in code, and the programs break on that line, you can change the code, then after stepping further, you are running modified code - this can help with small changes as it doesn't require to rebuild/redeploy the whole project. However it won't work in every case and it won't help if you don't want to change the workflow. Nevertheless I'm not sure what is causing so big difference in your case.

Comment: @Romasz Yea that's not useful either, really doesn't fit my workflow. The difference between our 2 tests could simply be that you have a much better computer, may i ask what processor you're using?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau It's i7, 7th generation. What is yours?

Comment: @Romasz I3-2120, sounds about right given that it's CPU bound (i have an ssd, and i see the cpu spike to max 1 core). Still sounds crazy slow in absolute terms compared to what i'm used to

Comment: @RonanThibaudau Compilation is done on one core, then if you see a spike during this couple of seconds, then looks like cpu is the answer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I definitely agree that UWP compilation is significantly slower than WPF. I've always had to break apart my WPF assemblies whenever I reached about 5-6 dozen xaml windows or views, in order to keep the incremental compilation times down at 10-20 seconds.  The way things are looking, my UWP assemblies will probably grow to only about 2 or 3 dozen items before they take way too long to compile.  Any assembly that takes over 10 seconds to compile is problematic when you are trying to do iterative coding & debugging.

Here are two recommendations, if you haven't tried them.  The first thing to do is go to the build tab and always remember to uncheck "compile with .NET native tool chain".  That is pretty useless for normal debug/test iterations.

The next thing to do is to monitor your build operations with procmon.  That will surface any issues that may be specific to your workstation (like virus scanning, other apps that may be interfering).

Here are the factors I noticed that would slow down UWP compilation compared to WPF:

- Lots of compilation passes (see them in the build output window):

```
> MarkupCompilePass1:
> XamlPreCompile:
> MarkupCompilePass2:
> GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
> CoreCompile:
> CopyGeneratedXaml:
> CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
> ComputeProcessXamlFiles:
> CustomOutputGroupForPackaging:
> GetPackagingOutputs:
> _GenerateProjectPriConfigurationFiles:
> _GenerateProjectPriFileCore:
```

- Core/Nuget dependencies

Unlike with the .Net Framework, all your dependencies for UWP are coming from .Net core and nuget.  You should be able to use procmon and see tons of reads against the directory where VS keeps the stuff: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages.  Note that the dependencies themselves aren't of a totally different quality than the .Net framework dependencies (in WPF).  But there is a big difference in how those dependencies are gathered and how they are pushed around in your output directories during compile operations (eventually ending up in the final Appx directory).

- No "shared output directory" for optimization.

With WPF we could send class library targets **individually** to a shared output directory (by checking them for build, while **unchecking** other libraries and the application exe itself).  Then we could launch the debugger and without compiling a whole ton of stuff that wasn't necessarily changing.  However, UWP requires us to build the entry-level application, regardless of whether we try to configure a shared output directory.

- The new "Deploy" step is required in UWP

WPF didn't have the new "deploy" step that is required every time you build a UWP app.  You will see the checkbox in the build configuration, and it applies to the entry-level application.  If you don't deploy, you won't see all your changes while debugging.

- UWP is still actively changing (unlike WPF)

They keep changing the UWP compilation operation.  Soon we are going to start to see something called the "WinUI" library that will introduce another dependency from NuGet for UWP apps.  This is probably not going to help matters where compilation performance is concerned.

I think once the pace of change starts to slow down, Microsoft may decide to focus on finding ways to improve the performance of compiles.  It seems pretty clear when reading the procmon output that less than half of the work done by devenv.exe is especially being done for me. The rest of it is pulling in all the dependencies so that my code can compile against it.  There has to be a way to optimize that repetitive processing.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorought answer, may i ask where you found the build steps documented (or did you dig into the build process yourself?). I'm already skipping the .net native pipeline for debugging but i'd like to find how the whole pipeline builds and check each component to find which one is slow and if maybe it's worth doing a custom compile? I already awarded you the bounty as your answer is perfect and clearly validate my issue and answers my question but it would be great if you could detail how you figured this out and how to repro the pipeline manually. In any case thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.  That's a first.  The compilation passes are listed in the output window if you set the MSBuild project output verbosity to Normal (or higher).  It also lists the total build time for each project ("Time Elapsed").at the end.

Comment: If you want to see even more about your build you can change the verbosity.  But I always find it more helpful to use procmon because it lists all the file I/O (and sometimes even a lot of network or registry activity).

On that note, another obvious suggestion for performance is to tell the nuget package manager not to download stuff during builds.

Comment: I don't fully understand the performance impact that arises because of the "Core/Nuget Dependencies" which are pulled in via UWP applications.  My WPF projects pulled in nuget dependencies too, but not nearly to the same degree as a UWP application.   I know that if you watch procmon you see file i/o that lists just about every assembly you've ever heard of and more.  But with WPF you could be selective and place dependencies on individual assemblies rather than bloated nuget packages.

Answer (score 2):

Ronan the (twelve-second?) compile time for an empty project does seem a bit high...  Mine generally runs for under five seconds (when empty).

You might want to watch what is going on with CPU.  The compilation of a single project should be entirely cpu-bound, especially on the second or third attempt, after the file system has cached your source code (and all the nuget dependencies are downloaded). You may want to keep an eye on task-manager and make sure that you are running at full speed on a single core (ie 25% if you have four cores, 12% for eight cores, etc).  If you see CPU drop down too far then something is going wrong.  Also make sure to check that CPU is **only** being used by the usual things that you would expect, eg devenv.exe, VBCSCompiler.exe and MSBuild.exe.

For those who claim to be compiling UWP projects so much faster than everyone else, it might be interesting to hear their benchmarks for the windows community toolkit. (https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/5.0.0)  The most interesting compile times would be for projects that are most heavy on xaml.  Here are my times:

- 10 seconds for Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls
- 8 seconds Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Graph
- 8 seconds Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid

The basic Van Arsdel inventory app is another thing to benchmark. https://github.com/Microsoft/InventorySample Here is my result:

- 14 seconds for Inventory.App

The VanArsdel sample app would be another good one to benchmark. (Careful with this; you may have to be on a Windows insider build and it may mess up your VS like it did mine).  The url is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vanarsdel  Here is my result:

- 13 seconds for VanArsdel project

Remember that projects which are heavily **xaml-oriented** are also usually the slowest because they involve more processing work during the various compilation passes.

**Using Diagnostic Output**

While the total elapsed time to build a project is critical, it may also be helpful to understand where the time is coming from.  You can get a summary of that if you go to Tools->Options->Build-and-Run and then turn up the project build output verbosity to Diagnostic.  Then compile the project in question.  At the end you will see a Task Performance Summary that looks like the following.  Note that CompileXaml should take the most time.  These five items seem to be pretty common.

Task Performance Summary:

```
  100 ms  ValidateAppxManifest                       1 calls
  400 ms  ExpandPriContent                           1 calls
  400 ms  Csc                                        2 calls
  600 ms  ResolveAssemblyReference                   1 calls
 7000 ms  CompileXaml                                2 calls
```

If you see anything else (eg GenerateAppxManifest) taking up a few seconds every time you compile then that is probably a corruption problem within your project.  You should be able to troubleshoot by searching for the word "completely", as in "Building target _GenerateCurrentProjectAppxManifest completely".  When you find that, it should tell you why it is doing the extra work.

**Min Version Targeting**

I noticed that changing the min version on the targeting tab will cut out three seconds out of my "CompileXaml" time.

See below that changing min version to 15063 helps cut down on compile time.  I suspect this is related to bloat in the related dependencies.

```
15063 (creators update) [4 seconds]
16299 (fall creators) [7 seconds]
17134 (version 1803) [ 7.5 seconds]
```

Its not always an option to target the creators update, so this may not be general-purpose fix.  But it is interesting to know about the impact of getting an updated Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: I recently opened a support case to find out why a change in min version targeting would increase xaml compile times.   Microsoft was able to acknowledge that they are aware of the issue.  Here is a link to their response on the visual studio developer community:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/376045/compilation-of-uwp-xaml-project-is-slower-when-tar.html

Comment: "We are aware of this issue and we'll be looking at addressing it in future Windows SDK releases.



This performance issue you that identified was introduced in an effort to address build consistency issues, especially in incremental compiler situations. With that in mind, we are looking at ways to make this better so the compile time impact is less."